# Bigquery Doesn't take the first column as header when importing from sheet

Tags: google-bigquery

i'm trying to create a table from a google sheet sheet, I marked the **header rows to skip** to 1, however when I import the data I find :

1. the columns name are : string_field_0, string_field_1 ...
2. the header raw values existed as data in the table

I checked that in the sheet the first raw (number 1) is the header

Comment: try header rows to skip = 0 ?

Comment: @keylen, that help in fact, when I choose header rows to skip = 0, i find that the header raw appears twice, then I locked in my data and found that it existe a second time, fare away from the 1 raw so I delete it

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: yes i resolve the issue

Comment: @aName if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error could be about 3 possible problems:

1.You need to set `“Header rows to skip”`, which is the number of rows that are at the top of the first row with data that includes the header or if there are some rows in blanks. You can do this in BigQuery UI.

[image]

2.Maybe all the header names are string type, with BigQuery you need to distinguish each header with something other than a String. In this case I will use integer. for example:

```
column1,column2,column3
foo,bar,1
cat,dog,2
fizz,buzz,3
```

You need to have something other than just Strings

3.You need to explicitly specify the schema yourself.

Comment: thank you for responding,
for action 1 and 3 that's exactly what I did, 
for action 2 I didn't understand it, its normal that header names are string (different string values)

Comment: @aName I updated my answer. You need to use something else than String, so BigQuery distinguish each header. In this case I use an integer in the columns name. "column1".